# Discord.py bot to disable send messages in all channel

Tags: discord.py

How can I have my bot disable all roles sending messages to all the channels?  The bot will be in multiple servers. I am using the discord.py rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate roles with [guild.roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20roles#discord.Guild.roles) and edit role [permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role%20edit#discord.Permissions) with [role.edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role%20edit#discord.Role.edit).

Comment: I guess I should have stated that I am a noob at making discord bots.  Any code that I can follow?

Comment: I'm sorry but you'll have to wait 6 or 7 hours (until 20h->21h GMT+00:00), I really need to sleep or my heart gonna break ^^'7 During this time try to do it by yourself and share your work to see if you're on the right track ;)

Comment: [This](https://www.codepile.net/pile/V8LQXj1w) should be a good base to work (don't forget to import all required → discord.py, asyncio, and to give to your bot all required permissions). Permissions keywords can be found in [discord api's official doc](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions#permissions)

Comment: Alright, I will take a look at it and see if I can figure it out.  I'll get back to you if all fails.